# Transient Markov chain

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Let $E$ be a countable set and $W \subset E$ a finite set. Consider an irreducible Markov chain $(X_n)_n$ taking values in with $E$ and having a transition probability $(P(x,y))_{x,y \in E}$. Consider a function $f:E \to \mathbb{R}_+$ such that $\inf_{x \in E}f(x)=0$ and $$\forall x \in E\setminus W,E_x[f(X_1)] \leq f(x),$$ $$\forall x \in W,f(x)>0.$$

Prove that $(X_n)_n$ is transient.

We note that for any initial distribution $\mu,$ $(f(X_n))_n$ is a $P_{\mu}$-supermartingale.

How can we use this to prove that $(X_n)_n$ is transient?

Comment: I must be missing something, because I don't see how it's possible. I mean, if the expected value is less than or equal to every $f(x)$, and $\inf f(x) = 0$, then the expected value has to be zero, but I don't see how the expected value of a positive function can be zero.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Maybe the same variable being used for quantification and expectation is confusing me. Since $f(x)$ has no positive lower bound, and the expectation is a lower bound for $f(x)$, then the expectation is non-positive, right?

Comment: $E_x[f(X_1)]$ is a constant, so I'm not sure what you mean by taking the infimum of it.

Comment: It isn't constant (it is a function of $x$)

Comment: How is $E_x[f(X_1)]$ a function of $x$? The expectation integrates out the $x$. I must not be understanding your notation.  Usually an expectation is a constant (the mean of some distribution), unless it is a conditional expectation.

Comment: @Joe $E_x$ denotes expectation with respect to the distribution of the Markov chain with initial distribution $\delta_x$, I.e. you start the chain at $X_0 = x$.

Comment: Ah, I see. I am use to the subscript indicating the variable with respect to which the expectation is taken. I am used to what you are saying being represented as $E[f(X_1)|X_0 = x]$

Comment: See https://services.math.duke.edu/~rtd/PTE/PTE5_011119.pdf theorem 5.3.8 and exercise 5.3.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $\epsilon>0$, choose $x$ in $E$ such that
$$f(x_0) <\epsilon \min_{w \in W} f(w) \quad (*) \,.$$
Denote $\tau=\inf\{n: X_n \in W\}$, with the convention that the empty set has infimum $\infty$. By optional stopping,
$$f(x_0) \ge E_x[f(X_\tau \wedge n)] \ge  P_x[\tau \le n]  \cdot \min_{w \in W} f(w) \,.$$  where $\wedge$ indicates minimum.
In conjunction with $(*)$ this yields
$P_x[\tau \le n] <\epsilon\,,$ which implies transience if we take $ n \to \infty$.

Comment: In an irreducible recurrent Markov chain, all hitting times are finite with probability1. See, e.g., Prop. 21.3 page 292 in  Levin, David A., and Yuval Peres. Markov chains and mixing times. second ed. Vol. 107. American Mathematical Soc., 2017.https://pages.uoregon.edu/dlevin/MARKOV/markovmixing.pdf

Comment: @Riro Pick a single point in W. When the chain hits it, the chain hits $W$.

Comment: We proved that there exists $x_0 \in E$ such that $P_{x_0}(\tau<+\infty)<1.$ I am having troubles understanding the last part of the proof. Does this imply that $x_0$ is transient? Or does it imply that there exists $y \in E$ (could also be $y \in W$) such that $y$ is transient?

Comment: In an irreducible chain, all states are transient or they are all recurrent. In the recurrent case, from any starting state, the probability to hit each target is 1. Pick the  starting state $x$ in my answer, a target state $w \in W$, and you get that the chain cannot be recurrent.